# Uncaught TypeError: n.get(...).then is not a function StackTrace Error

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, stack-trace

My code is looking like this. This (Attached Image) is the error I'm getting, I have installed StackTrace with the respected npm command. Did I miss something here? An imported it, 
**import * as StackTrace from 'stack-trace';**

```
public handleError(error: any) {
    const message = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    window.onerror = function(msg, file, line, col) {
    // StackTrace.fromError(error).then(callback).catch(errback);
};
const callbackFun = function(stackframes) {
    const stringifiedStack = stackframes.map(function(sf) {
        return sf.toString();
    }).join('\n');
};
const errback = function(err) { console.log(err.message); };
StackTrace.get().then(callbackFun).catch(errback);
}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to be an import issue. Please provide the exact library you are using ([npm.js](https://www.npmjs.com/) link).

Comment: Hey @MikeDrakoulelis I have added **npm install stacktrace-js** and inserted **'http://cdnjs.com/libraries/stacktrace.js'** in script tag, in indext.html.

Comment: Try to log the value of error and see what's inside. According to official docs `fromError` method is expecting an `Error` instance.